# Javascript Sort by Date

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I have a JavaScritpt Date sorting question. I have an array of up to 24 dates that I need to sort in descending order. The dates were formatted in a full date format. I successfully converted to a mm/dd/yyyy.  I realized that I cannot use sort and I believe I need to run a comparisons of sort.

My dates appear as below

```
eventDatesArrray = ,11/30/2014,12/31/2018,12/31/2013,10/11/2016,10/12/2015
```

I did reference [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date). My apologies, but I do not believe I completely understand how it works since the I continue to receive an error message stating that I am not passing the parameters. Not certain how to pass a and b to this function.

```
var sortedEventDates = eventDatesArrray .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help. 
Allison

Comment: This link might help u:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: Thank you Nihar! I tired your suggestion, but unfortuantely still a bit stumped. I edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dates are strings:

```
dates = ["10/12/2014", "12/12/2015", "12/31/2015", "14/08/2015"]

dates.sort(function(a, b) {
    var parseDate = function parseDate(dateAsString) {
            var dateParts = dateAsString.split("/");
            return new Date(parseInt(dateParts[2], 10), parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, parseInt(dateParts[0], 10));
        };

    return parseDate(b) - parseDate(a);
});
```

> ["12/31/2015", "12/12/2015", "14/08/2015", "10/12/2014"]

Comment: You don't need to use *parseInt*, `new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0])` is just fine as the Date constructor accepts string values too. You can also simply do: `return parsedDateA - parsedDateB` since the subtraction operator will coerce the Dates to number (their internal time value). :-) Oh, and `parsedDateA === parsedDateB` will never be true since Dates are Objects, and Objects are never equal to each other (whether using `==` or `===`).

Answer (score 0):

Or in ES6 :

```
var eventDatesArrray = ["11/30/2014","12/31/2018","12/31/2013","10/11/2016","10/12/2015"];
var dates = eventDatesArrray.map(elem => new Date(elem)).sort((a,b) => a-b);
console.log(dates); //[ Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid),
                    //  Sun Nov 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid),
                    //  Mon Oct 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
                    //  Tue Oct 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)),
                    //  Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid) ]
```

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is not recommended as it's almost entirely implementation dependent. Manually parse strings with a library or bespoke function (per Adnrzej's answer).

Answer (score 0):

For example, we assumed we have this list of date values:

```
const value = ["2021-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000", "2023-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000", "2019-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000"];
```

To sort I use this way and it works fine for me .

```
const sortedValue = value.sort((a,b)=> new Date(a) - new Date(b));

console.log(sortedValue);
```

//Result => ["2019-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000", "2021-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000", "2023-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000"]

```
const sortedValue2 = value.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b) - new Date(a));

console.log(sortedValue2);
```

//Result => ["2023-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000", "2021-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000", "2019-04-06T00:00:00.000+0000"]

Answer (score -1):

You could use this as a custom comparator function:

```
function compare (a, b) {
    partsA = a.split("/");
    partsB = b.split("/");
    if (partsA[2] > partsB[2]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (partsA[2] < partsB[2]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (partsA[1] > partsB[1]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (partsA[1] < partsB[1]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (partsA[0] > partsB[0]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (partsA[0] < partsB[0]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `eventDatesArray.sort(compare);`